# How do I correctly use setInterval and clearInterval to switch between two different functions?

Tags: javascript, animation, counter, setinterval, clearinterval

For practice I am trying to display a number that increments from 0 - 9, then decrements from 9 - 0, and infinitely repeats.
The code that I have so far seems to be close, but upon the second iteration the `setInterval` calls of my 2 respective functions `countUp` and `countDown` seem to be conflicting with each other, as the numbers displayed are not counting in the intended order... and then the browser crashes.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Algorithm Test</title>
    </head>

    <body onload = "onloadFunctions();">
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            function onloadFunctions()
            {
                countUp();
                setInterval(countUp, 200);
            }

            var count = 0;
            function countUp()
            {
                document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = count;
                count++;

                if(count == 10)
                {
                    clearInterval(this);
                    countDown();
                    setInterval(countDown, 200);
                }
            }
            function countDown()
            {
                document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = count;
                count--;

                if(count == 0)
                {
                    clearInterval(this);
                    countUp();
                    setInterval(countUp, 200);
                }       
            }
        </script>

        From 0 - 9, up and down:&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id = "here"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to capture the return value from `setInterval( ... )` into a variable as that is the reference to the timer:

```
var interval;
var count = 0;

function onloadFunctions()
{
    countUp();
    interval = setInterval(countUp, 200);
}

/* ... code ... */

function countUp()
{
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = count;
    count++;

    if(count === 10)
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
        countUp();
        interval = setInterval(countUp, 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

@Claude, you are right, the other solution I proposed was too different from original code. This is another possible solution, using `setInterval` and switching functions:

```
function onloadFunctions() {
    var count = 0;
    var refId = null;
    var target = document.getElementById("aux");

    var countUp = function() {
        target.innerHTML = count;
        count ++;
        if(count >= 9) {
            window.clearInterval(refId);
            refId = window.setInterval(countDown, 500);
        }
    }

    var countDown = function() {
        target.innerHTML = count;
        count --;
        if(count <= 0) {
            window.clearInterval(refId);
            refId = window.setInterval(countUp, 500);
        }
    }
    refId = window.setInterval(countUp, 500);
}
```

Comment: Nice implementation with closure, like it.

Answer (score 4):

`clearInterval(this);`.  You can't do that.  You need to save the return value from `setInterval`.

```
var interval;
function onloadFunctions()
{
    countUp();
    interval = setInterval(countUp, 200);
}

var count = 0;
function countUp()
{
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = count;
    count++;

    if(count == 10)
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
        countDown();
        interval = setInterval(countDown, 200);
    }
}
function countDown()
{
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = count;
    count--;

    if(count == 0)
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
        countUp();
        interval = setInterval(countUp, 200);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
...
<body onload = "onloadFunctions();">

    <script>
        var cup, cdown; // intervals
        var count = 0,
            here  = document.getElementById("here");

        function onloadFunctions() {
            cup = setInterval(countUp, 200);
        }

        function countUp() {
            here.innerHTML = count;
            count++;

            if(count === 10) {
                clearInterval(cup);
                cdown = setInterval(countDown, 200);
            }
        }
        function countDown() {   
            here.innerHTML = count;
            count--;

            if(count === 0) {
                clearInterval(cdown);
                cup = setInterval(countUp, 200);
            }       
        }
    </script>

    From 0 - 9, up and down:&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id = "here"></div>
</body>
```

you could also create a single reference to `#here` element. Use always `===` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem, the following is my suggestion:

```
function onloadFunctions() {
    var count = 0;
    var delta = 1;
    var target = document.getElementById("here");
    var step = function() {
        if(count <= 0) delta =  1;
        if(count >= 9) delta = -1;
        count += delta;
        target.innerHTML = count;
        window.setTimeout(step, 500);
    }
    step ();
}
```

PS: it's safer to use `setTimeout` than `setInteval`.

Comment: If I was writing my own code, I might prefer a solution such as yours. But, the questioner is trying something for practice -- namely hopping back and forth between two different functions. You didn't actually answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /** Tools */
const log = require('ololog').configure({
  locate: false
})

let count = 0
let interval__UP
let interval__DOWN

function countUp () {
  count++
  log.green('countUp(): ', count)

  if (count == 5) {
    clearInterval(interval__UP)
    interval__DOWN = setInterval(function () {
      countDown()
    }, 1000)
  }

}

function countDown () {

  count--
  log.red('countDown(): ', count)

  if (count == 0) {
    clearInterval(interval__DOWN)
    interval__UP = setInterval(function () {
      countUp()
    }, 3000)
  }
}

function start () {
  countUp()
  log.cyan('start()')
  interval__UP = setInterval(function () {
    countUp()
  }, 2000)
}

start()
```

[Console Log shows it's working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFJeU.png)

Comment: It answers the 3 parts of the question.  (1) How do I correctly setInterval (2) and clearInterval (3) to switch between two different functions?

Comment: When the count satisfies the condition in the IF statement the two different functions countUp() and countDown() clear the previous interval, sets a new interval, which switches to the opposite count function.  -- if you run this in node it works perfectly.