# Javascript countdown form submit not working

Tags: javascript

So I was trying to write some javascript to countdown and then submit the form when the countdown is finished. This is the JS I found online and tried to implement:

```
 var seconds = 300;

 function secondPassed() {
   var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60),
     remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

   if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
     remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
   }

   document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
   if (seconds == 0) {
     clearInterval(countdownTimer);
     document.qForm.submit();
   } else {
     seconds--;
   }
 }
 var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

Here it is implemented:
https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/9p9o4k6s/1/

The error says: **secondPassed is not defined** but I'm not sure why that is. Could anyone please explain where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Change it to `setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);` Please see [**setInterval Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for more details

Comment: I know this possible duplicate of [**How do I correctly use setInterval and clearInterval to switch between two different functions?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485385/how-do-i-correctly-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval-to-switch-between-two-diffe) is asking for more than just clear and set interval but it shows how to use it correctly by no specifying the function reference as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me both ways of calling `setInterval` work well with SO snippet. I think bug can be jsfiddle specific as it seems it accepts only the first form of `setInterval`, which takes function and interval, not code string to execute and delay (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). If you want to keep using fiddle you will have to change last line to:

```
var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

```js
         var seconds = 300;

         function secondPassed() {
           var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60),
             remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

           if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
             remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
           }

           document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
           if (seconds == 0) {
             clearInterval(countdownTimer);
             document.qForm.submit();
           } else {
             seconds--;
           }
         }
         var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

canvas {}

time {color: red; float: right;}

.active {color: green; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
  <h3>Question 1 of 20<time id="countdown">5:00</time></h3>
  <form name="qForm">
    <input type="radio"> 219
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in last line of your code. Change that line to this'

```
var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

Here is the updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/9p9o4k6s/3/

Comment: Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval. There is no error there, `setInterval` can take code in stringas first arg

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a function call as a string to `setInterval` like that, the function you're calling must be in the global scope. Your function `secondPassed` is wrapped by the jsFiddle onload wrapper and so it is not in the global scope.

To demonstrate this, if you did `window.secondPassed = secondPassed;` to put it in the global scope, your existing code would work.

The proper solution is to pass the function object as the argument instead of a string:

```
var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

Note there are no parenthesis `()` when used in this way.